# Why is sum of squared PCA column loadings equal to corresponding Eigenvalue?

Tags: categorical-data, pca, multivariate-analysis, eigenvalues

I'm wondering why or how is the sum of squared PCA loadings **in the column** equal to Eigenvalue. I understood that the sum of squared PCA loadings **in the row** is equal to 1 or 100% because original variables are standardized and each variance of the original variable is 100% explained by PCs. Also, I understood each squared loading can be a **' proportion'** of the variance of each original variable that the PCs explain. However, when it comes to the columns my understanding is so confused. I don't know the logic that how the sum of squared PCA loadings can be equal to eigenvalue, the variance of PC, and the meaning of each squared loading when it comes to the eigenvalue.
[image]